# JQuery Tabs: How to get a list of the tab titles

Tags: jquery, tabs

As the title suggest, my question is what is the best way to get or build a list of the titles for the set of tabs. I was thinking I would have to build the list in a for loop, but there does not appear to be any 'name' or 'title' property where you could do something like this:

```
var $tabs = $('contentContainer').tabs();
$tabs.tabs( 'title', index );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('contentContainer ul li a').each(function(){alert($(this).text())})
```

(assuming the selector is used when creating the tabs is 'contentContainer'... if it's a class or an id it will need a . or a #.)

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer looks pretty good, except that it searches recursively; so, if you had any lists nested inside of your tabs this would pick those up too. I would propose a slight modification

```
 $('> ul > li > a', tabSelector).each(function () { alert($(this).text()) })
```

This will tell jquery to only select direct descendants.